# Selenium WebDriver Setting debuggerAddress Stopped Working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium Web driver, however, I am preloading a browser by setting the debuggerAddress. I connect through a specified port. I had this working great. Suddenly, it's stopped working. I'm not quite sure what the issue is.

```
public void launchBrowser() throws InterruptedException {
        
        try {
         
            // Set file path of chrome driver
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
            
            // Start chrome driver with existing chrome browser 
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress","localhost:1250");
            
            // Create object
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            
            // Write to console where we are
            System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
            
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
         
            console("JacksClass.java","launchBrowser()", "Exception: " + e);
            
        }
        
    }
```

Before I run the script. I start the Chrome browser with this command in CMD

```
start chrome --remote-debugging-port=1250
```

After launching the browser from CMD successfully. Then running the code. I get the following exception after around 1-2 minutes.

```
JacksClass.java - launchBrowser() : Exception: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-6', revision: '5f43a29cfc'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-5H32IOI', ip: '192.168.1.53', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.8'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

All of this was working great a month ago. I have the chrome driver installed in the same location.

[image]

Comment: Removing the ChromeOptions works. It loads the browser at run time. However, my above code does not do as inteneded. I have this working perfectly no so long ago. I don't understand why it might not be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work. Firstly I tried to access the open port in another browser.

Typing `localhost:1250` into the URL bar.

It could not connect. So there clearly was an issue with that port. I have tried many different ports but still had the same issue.

I finally tried port 1258 and then double-checked it with the test outlined above. Typing `localhost:1258` into another browser proved the port was active.

Then my program worked as well! How strange! Glad it's working now :)